# separate logfiles for every minute not always generated

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to set up logging where all logs from every minute will end up in a separate file. This is the setup I have:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import time

logging.basicConfig(
    format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(name)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    handlers=[TimedRotatingFileHandler("test.log", when="m", interval=1, backupCount=10, utc=True)],
)
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.error("asdf")
```

When I ran the script multiple times, this is what I found in `test.log.2020-01-01_22-16`:

```
[2022-01-01 22:15:46] ERROR in __main__: asdf
[2022-01-01 22:15:55] ERROR in __main__: asdf
[2022-01-01 22:16:06] ERROR in __main__: asdf
[2022-01-01 22:16:14] ERROR in __main__: asdf
[2022-01-01 22:16:15] ERROR in __main__: asdf
[2022-01-01 22:16:45] ERROR in __main__: asdf
[2022-01-01 22:16:56] ERROR in __main__: asdf
```

Can anyone please explain how come that `test.log.2020-01-01_22-15` does not even exist and the records that I would assume to be in there are found in the `22:16` log instead?

EDIT: I found out that a new file is only generated if there is a whole minute when nothing was logged. Can I somehow achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the [`TimedRotatingFileHandler` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) says so :

> When computing the next rollover time for the first time (when the handler is created), the last modification time of an existing log file, or else the current time, is used to compute when the next rotation will occur.

Which is a correct translation for the corresponding code from [`TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L250) :

```py
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            t = os.stat(filename)[ST_MTIME]
        else:
            t = int(time.time())
```

It is intended for long-running applications. If what you want is to have the same behavior for your short-running application, you will have to write some custom code.
Re-using as much as possible from `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, we could cheat with modification times.

```py
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import time
import datetime
import os
import re
import stat


def cheat_logfile_mtime():
    filename = "test.log"
    with open(filename, "rt") as logfile:
        first_line = logfile.readline().rstrip()
    pattern = re.compile(r"\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})]")  # [2022-01-03 16:06:07]
    match = pattern.match(first_line)
    assert match is not None
    logline_datetime_str = match.group(1)
    local_timezone = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo
    logline_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(logline_datetime_str).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone()
    file_mtime_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(filename)[stat.ST_MTIME], tz=local_timezone)
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=local_timezone)
    one_minute_delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    if now - file_mtime_datetime < one_minute_delta < now - logline_datetime:
        # the logfile was last modified less than one minute ago, but was first written more than one minute ago
        os.utime("test.log", (logline_datetime.timestamp(), logline_datetime.timestamp()))
        print("cheating the file mtime")


cheat_logfile_mtime()


logging.basicConfig(
    format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(name)s: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    handlers=[TimedRotatingFileHandler("test.log", when="m", interval=1, backupCount=10, utc=True)],
)
logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.error("asdf")
```

This works as you wanted : a logfile will not contain more than 1 real minute of logs, whatever the number of times you start the application. I tested it with 1 run by second, getting ~59 lines in the file before the rotation.
It seems to respect the user timezone (I am currently in CET). But it requires being able to reliably read and write modification times, which may not be able on network drives or other conditions.